# What options, if any, imply /CLR in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, static-linking

I'm trying to build my 64 bit project in 32 bit mode.
All the dependencies are compiled as static libs /MT, and the project/dependencies do not have common language runtime support selected in the project configuration.

Yet I still get this(for the 32 bit build):

```
    1>cl : Command line error D8016: '/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible
```

Aside from being 32 bit/linked to 32 bit versions of my dependencies, the configuration is essentially identical to my 64 bit project.

So I was wondering if there was something in Win32 that could imply /CLR that i might have turned on somewhere in my configuration or if there was a way to see what was using the /CLR option.

Comment: There isn't a /clr flag.

Comment: You misunderstand me, there is no **/CLR** flag **selected**, neither the command line nor the project settings show /CLR **as being selected**, the General section shows "No Common Language Runtime Support", and there is no /CLR flag in the list of command line options currently shown.

Comment: Rather than looking through the UI, try doing a text search within the unloaded proj file, to see if there are any configurations/platforms that have the /clr flag set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, seems one of the individual CPP files had CLR enabled in its properties.